# Track changes to a sharepoint list item

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-2010, auditing

We are developing a system using SharePoint 2010 Foundataion.

We would like to track all changes made to a list. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only need to turn on [Versioning](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1692-how-to-enable-sharepoint-document-version-control/) in the Document Library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but our list is not a document library it is based on a custom list definition.

Comment: You can still enable Version control on lists.

Comment: Is there a way to log EVERYTHING that happens? I turned on major and minor versioning but I have some files that are disappearing and they aren't in the recycle bin.  Don't know what is happening, can I track this some how?

Answer (score 1):

You can have full version history for a List - if this is not enough then perhaps an event handler associated with the list that logs all addition/update/delete events.